# virtualenvwrapper syntax error while setting up for python in powershell

Tags: python, powershell, syntax

At the moment I'm following this [guide](http://newcoder.io/begin/setup-your-machine/) to set up python with the purpose of making a python scraper. I'm attempting to install Vitualenvwrapper which should be a simple pip command but I keep getting a syntax error. I have attempted the fixes listed (even though the one I have found don't list a syntax error as a problem). Can anyone shed some light on this for me?

```
$ C:\Users\nik> pip install virtualenvwrapper-powershell
    Collecting virtualenvwrapper-powershell
    Using cached virtualenvwrapper-powershell-12.7.8.zip
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\nik\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-c37hzy_b\virtualenvwrapper-powershell\setup.py", line 76
        TOKEN_READ = 0x00020000L | 0x0008
                               ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax 
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\nik\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-c37hzy_b\virtualenvwrapper-powershell\
```

Comment: Looks like you're trying to run Python 2.x code in Python 3.x. (The syntax `0x00020000L` used to make a long integer, now it's an error). I see the guide you link says "*you will need Python 2.x*"

Comment: I have both version of python so that might be it, I'll try uninstalling one and get back to you

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that its defaulting to using Python 3.x. You probably have a reference to Python3.x in your environment PATH.

Open System your machine, go to Advanced Settings -> Environment Variables and edit your PATH. Remove entries for Python3.x and leave the Python2.7 entries behind.

Open up PowerShell, type python, hit enter and verify that python 2.7 runs.

Re-run your command:

```
pip install virtualenvwrapper-powershell
```

Then you should find it all works.

Of course be aware that removing Python3.x from your path might affect other things that you may be using python3 for, so just remember the entries you removed in case in the future you find anything not working that relied on python3.